# Timeout exception error scraping with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

im trying to scrape table based on dates from this site https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx with this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import re
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Import webdriver to initialise a browser
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# click "usd"



book = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,' //*[@id="selectPeriod"]/option[range]'))
)
book.click()

book1 = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,' //*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_ddlmatauang1"]/option[USD]'))
)
book1.click()



start_date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_txtFrom")
start_date.send_keys("20-Nov-15")
end_date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_txtTo")
end_date.send_keys("20-Nov-20")
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_btnSearch1").click()
```

but instead i got this error and i dont know why.can anybody help me what goes wrong?

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 9
> 10
> ---> 11 book = wait.until(
> 12     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,' //*[@id="selectPeriod"]/option[range]'))
> 13 )
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in
> until(self, method, message)
> 78             if time.time() > end_time:
> 79                 break
> ---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> 81
> 82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):
>
> TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: "Selenium will wait for a maximum of 10 seconds for an element matching the given criteria to be found. If no element is found in that time, a TimeoutException is thrown." Try increasing the wait, or make sure the xpath is correct?

Comment: hm the results still same..and the xpath im sure its right tho..

Comment: I've never used an option in a wait for clickable, so I'm not sure if it would work or you need to separate it and click it separately

Comment: If the results are still the same I recommend trying to go through website's html, and try and piece together how you can get there manually by navigating with BeautifulSoup once you use get page source. That's how I used to do it. It does take quite a while to figure out the structure, before you can automate the process in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work since it's a Select tag.

```
driver.get("https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
book = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"selectPeriod")))
sel = Select(book)
sel.select_by_value("range")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Comment: thank you ! but i got 1 more problem,the submit button wont work! 
submit_button=driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_btnSearch1").click()

can you help me?

Comment: The id seems dynamic which means it'll change.//input[@value='Search'] Use the following xpath instead.